# Calling stored procedure with a fixed length binary parameter using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have a problem calling stored procedures with a fixed length binary parameter using Entity Framework. The stored procedure ends up being called with 8000 bytes of data no matter what size byte array I use to call the function import. To give some example, this is the code I am using.

```
byte[] cookie = new byte[32];  
 byte[] data = new byte[2];  
entities.Insert("param1", "param2", cookie, data);
```

The parameters are `nvarchar(50)`, `nvarchar(50)`, `binary(32)`, `varbinary(2000)`

When I run the code through SQL profiler, I get this result.

```
exec [dbo].[Insert] @param1=N'param1',@param2=N'param2',@cookie=0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

[SNIP because of 16000 zeros]

```
,@data=0x0000
```

All parameters went through ok other than the `binary(32)` cookie. The `varbinary(2000)` seemed to work fine and the correct length was maintained.

Is there a way to prevent the extra data being sent to SQL server? This seems like a big waste of network resource.

Answer (score 1):

Use varbinary instead of binary. Helpfull for me

Answer (score 0):

EF 4 always uses largish params, because using param-size = data-size mostly means that the query can't be re-used with new param values, so SQL can't cache the queries for you. In other words, what it's doing now is probably more efficient overall than using a smaller param, if your data size ever changes.

If your data size never changes, then use a different column width.